# Adding value of rows from row values of same column by id matching in long data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset data1 where for some participants data is collected for different timepoints

```
data1 <- data.frame(id=c(10239, 10239,10239,10240, 10240,10240, 10241, 10242,10242,10242,10242,10242, 10243, 10243,10243,10243,10243,10244, 10245, 10246, 10247,10247,10247,10247,10247, 10248), var1=c(2,NA,NA, 3,NA,NA, 8, 4, NA,NA,NA,NA, 5, NA,NA,NA,NA,5, 7, 9, 8,NA,NA,NA,NA,8),var2=c(23,NA,NA, 45,NA,NA,67, 87, NA,NA,NA,NA, 22, NA,NA,NA,NA,15, 90, 19, 80,NA,NA,NA,NA, 34))
```

Here, data for var1 and var2 is entered only at one time point and in the next time point it is just entered as NA.
Now based on the first variable i.e. id - I need to replace the NA values of var1 and var2 with the value in the first time point i.e. first it appears. I want the output to be like this.

Can someone point the best way to do this?

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill the values (they go down by default but you change by specifying direction).

```
library(tidyverse)
data1 %>% fill(var1,var2)
```